# What is the name of this github feature?

Tags: github

When you have a directory that has only a single child that is also a directory, github "jumps" to the last directory that has more than one child (or that is just the last directory anyway), and shows this directory instead of the original directory.

A example can be found in this gray dir in my screenshot:

`scala/com/gravity/goose`

I tried a lot to discover the specific name of this feature, but I couldn't find it or any reference in a github post.

PS: The reason I am trying to discover the name is that I'm looking for the same behaviour when navigating directories in a shell.

[image: Feature]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features name is Folder jumping.

http://github.com/blog/1877-folder-jumping

Comment: Oh man, I googled for nested folders, collapse directories, subdirectories, subfolders, joining nested folders, nested directories merge, and a lot of combinations like those. I even tried to search inside github's blog. And then I give up and post this question in Stackoverflow, uses the term "jump"  for the first time when asking the question trying to explain the behaviour. After that, I just forget to search for this also: "jump". 

Thanks a lot for your response! :)

Comment: It is relatively new feature i was curious when it was launched and founded in the blog. I remember it from that ;)